how to pack a cart with gear?
I have a canopy-enclosed cart (inside cargo space: 34 x 24 x 8 inches), which I want to fill up with gear.
The challenge is that I'd need to empty the cart about twice a day and lift all the stuff, group by group, (including the cart itself) few hundred meters / yards due to unmaneuverable conditions for wheels.
Therefore the packing system needs to make it easy to carry all the stuff without too many back and forth.
I figured to get 3 bags (55L x 2, 40L x1), and stack them on top of each other inside the cart (40L on top), however, I am afraid I won't be able to secure them well enough with straps, and that they might fall on the canopy. also its still not the best because it would require at least 3 trips each time.
A pulk would have been great, but I can't find a collapsible one, that would allow my to carry it inside or on top of the cart.
What would you suggest please?
Thanks!

That's a lot of stuff for one person. What are the dimensions of the bags? Can two of them fit in the cart side by side or will it be a stack of 3. Also how can things under a canopy fall on a canopy?

I found bags that are about the exact dimensions of the L (24'') and W (8'').
they cannot fit side by side because the W of 8'' is too small for any 2 bags to fit side by side.
The canopy encloses all the cart, kind of a wind-rain protection.

A few more details please - are you pulling/pushing the cart yourself?  Does it have poles? Could you add a couple of loose poles to make a travois for the rough sections - carry cart and all on the travois.

Plenty of waterproof haul bags around from the climbing or canoe/kayak communities. Depending on length of carry and weight of equipment I think you could get all the cargo in one (slow) go and then wrestle with the cart. Slinging packs front and back works OK for a hundred meters or so, just go slow.

@JonCuster sounds nice, however, i cant imagine being able to stuff 3 smaller sacks (i.e. two 55L and one 40L) into one haul bag as large as it'd be.

@kolmer - you misunderstand - most haul bags have fairly rudimentary straps already to, well, haul them around. They just won't be comfortable all day on your back. Less weight per unit volume. Get two bags that together exceed the capacity of the cart, don't fill them up completely. Now you have two bags to balance, one front and one back to schlep the hundred meters.

@JonCuster regarding the weight you mentioned, they are very heavy. for example, 40L duffel bag weighs 2 lbs 4.9 oz (1045 g) while 46L haul bag weight 4 lbs. 11 oz. (2.1 kg)

Then get duffel bags and figure out how to carry those (and search more widely for bag options). If weight is such a critical issue then perhaps there are other solutions to your trip that don't involve a cart and all that gear.

Welcome to TGO. Do you have any photos of the cart? Are you pulling, pushing, or bike towing? And what does "fall on the canopy" mean? Isn't the canopy the lid? Why can you not modify the cart so that it can properly allow use of straps? Finally, do you really expect to carry the cart and its whole load in just 2 trips?  Please [edit] any and all of the extra info into the body of the question.

@kolmer Those weights are pretty light for bag + contents. I've carried over 45 kg  (99 lb) routinely in a backpack for work doing ecological surveys off-trail etc. There has to be a solution, but you need to edit a lot of detail into the question - see Martin F comment above.

Also how long is the total daily hike? One massive backpack (e.g. 90L, but I've seen 120L online) for most of it,  light stuff in a smaller backpack worn on the front (30-40L) and strap a couple of light drybags outside.  Then do away with the cart entirely.  It's worth a bit of effort to avoid lifting the cart over a few hundred metres a couple of times a day as that's going to get very tiring very fast.  The rest of the terrain might not be very friendly for wheels either and a broken cart would leave you stuck under your plan.

(I assume all the stuff is strictly necessary; that's another discussion)

Find or make bags that fit two side by side inside the cart and put the third or maybe third and fourth on top fixed with elastic straps or easy to place and release adjustable webbing straps. Use the straps to hold the load, not the canopy.
If you have four bags it is likely that you can put the top layer at a 90° angle to the lower layer, adding stability.
Or make (or have made) bags to replace your bigger bags so that they fit the cart.
Alternatively, build or rebuild the cart to fit the bags you own.
